# OpenAM reset password email sending to old email id

Tags: openam, opendj, forgerock

I am using Forgerock OpenAM 13.0.0 as an identity provider.

I have tried email Id change and resetting the password through REST API. But when I tried to reset the password it is sending Email to the old email. I didn't see any reference to old email in openam or opendj, I wait for 24 hr still it is sending to the old email, it fixes only after restarting the openam server. any quick fix or alternative way to send to the correct email?

Comment: I found it is because of global user data caching. The below URL helped to resolve this issue https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/admin-guide/index.html#turn-off-global-user-data-caching